How to fetch only the coverage results of lines, branches & functions from console in batch scripting in GCOV
gcovr -v -b -r .^
 --xml-pretty^
 -o ".\reports\publish\coverage.xml"^
 --sort-percentage^
 -s ^
 --exclude=".*(abcd_|_abcd|-xy|xy_|_xy($|\/)|APK_GENERATED).*" || goto :error

When this command is executed, console log has various info on this execution. At last this gcovr command provides the coverage values of lines, functions and branches.
(DEBUG) Gathered coveraged data for 23 files

lines: 99.9% (1104 out of 1105)
functions: 100.0% (142 out of 142)
branches: 96.6% (312 out of 323)

Requirement:
I need to redirect only the coverage values to another file. The file should look like

lines: 99.9%
functions: 100.0%
branches: 96.6%


The incorrect/invalid use of smart-quotes in your code, (“ ”), over the correct/valid dumb-quotes, ("), require fixing in your question. I have noticed also that you're using –xml-pretty, which not only should be --xml-pretty, but was superseeded by --cobertura-pretty back in v5.1. As it is currently at v8.2, you should really tell us which version you are using, and use the newer option if later than v5.0. Also –sort-percentage should be -p or --sort-percentage, and –exclude should be -e or --exclude.

As an additional observation, I cannot see any correlation between the output you have shown and results in indented xml!

If the lines of output you have shown are displayed only on the console window, and not in the xml file, then the obvious reason is that this is sent to stderr, (and the -o to stdout). You should therefore try changing the end of your command to 2>".\reports\publish\coverage.log" || GoTo error instead of just || goto :error. Then open and check that file afterwards, just to verify that.

may i know then from which part of gcovr the coverage values are executed

lines: 99.9% (1104 out of 1105)
functions: 100.0% (142 out of 142)
branches: 96.6% (312 out of 323)


Have you tried doing what I just asked? gcovr -v -r -o ".\reports\publish\coverage.xml" -p --cobertura-pretty -b -s -e ".*(abcd_|_abcd|-xy|xy_|_xy($|\/)|APK_GENERATED).*" 2>".\reports\publish\coverage.log", and looked to see if those lines are in the coverage.log file?

@compo Much Thanks for the command, i got exactly what i needed
lines: 39.1% (496 out of 1268)
functions: 52.2% (82 out of 157)
branches: 36.8% (135 out of 367)

Well, technically you only wanted part of that output so perhaps the following single line batch file command would suit you better: @(For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%G In ('gcovr -v -r -o ".\reports\publish\coverage.xml" -p --cobertura-pretty -b -s -e ".*(abcd_|_abcd|-xy|xy_|_xy($|\/)|APK_GENERATED).*"') Do @Echo %%G %%H) >"reports\publish\coverage.log".

gcovr -v -r -o ".\reports\publish\coverage.xml" -p --cobertura-pretty -b -s -e ".(abcd_|abcd|-xy|xy|_xy($|/)|APK_GENERATED)." 2>".\reports\publish\coverage.log"
from this command i need to check the coverage values and make the pipeline fail ,if value of any the parameter is less than 90.
:: Initialize coverage variables

set line_coverage=0
set function_coverage=0
set branch_coverage=0


::Extract coverage percentages from the log file
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /i "lines:" .\reports\publish\gcovr_output.log') do (
set line_coverage=%%a
)
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /i "functions:" .\reports\publish\gcovr_output.log') do (
set function_coverage=%%a
)
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /i "branches:" .\reports\publish\gcovr_output.log') do (
set branch_coverage=%%a
)
::Clean up the percentages by removing extra spaces and converting to numbers
set line_coverage=!line_coverage: =!

But this is unable to decide the pipeline should fail or not

The question is supposed to be in the question area, where everybody can read and understand what the particular programming issue is, that you equire us to assist you with. I am not your personal tech helper, and should not be answering your ever changing requirements in the comment area. You need to completely overhaul the entire question, but also be respectful that somebody has already answered you, and what they submitted may be so far away from your changes that they may not be best pleased. IMO, you should post a new question asking only about parsing the exact content of your file.

If you're doing scripting, you may find it easier to extract data from the gcovr JSON Summary. If you want to fail a CI pipeline if total coverage drops below a percentage,  you can use the gcovr --fail-under-line 90 option.

I feel --cobertura-pretty is much simpler than JSON summary. Can i use gcov --fail alsong with  --cobertura-pretty ?

can i use gcovr --fail-under-function 90 .\reports\publish\gcovr_output.log this command?

Why don't you try it? gcovr -v -r --fail-under-line 90 --fail-under-branch 90 --fail-under-function 90 -o ".\reports\publish\coverage.xml" -p --cobertura-pretty -b -s -e ".*(abcd_|_abcd|-xy|xy_|_xy($|\/)|APK_GENERATED).*" 2>"reports\publish\coverage.log", then on the next command/line Echo %ErrorLevel%. Also , do you actually need the output, if you have the exit codes? If , for example your errorlevel is 2, 4, 6, 16, 18, 20, 22 you would know that there was a failure, and where.

is there any way i can get the failure reason? Like line function failed becuase of some % which is less than 90%

i checked when line coverage is more than 90%. even now it gives exit 2

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q79181907.txt"

:: remove variables starting coverage
FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set coverage 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="

:: Set fieldnames required

SET "fields=lines functions branches"

FOR /f "tokens=1,2usebackqdelims=:." %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 rem %%b=fieldname; %%c=value
 FOR %%e IN (%fields%) DO IF /i "%%e"=="%%b" SET /a coverage_%%e=%%c
)

:: Check values

FOR  /F "tokens=2*delims==_" %%b In ('set coverage 2^>Nul') DO IF %%c lss 97 ECHO %%b is low

SET coverage
GOTO :EOF

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both usebackq and the quotes around %filename1% can be  omitted.
I used a file named q79181907.txt containing your data for my testing.
Likely that
FOR /f "tokens=1,2usebackqdelims=:." %%b IN ('gcovr -v -h…') do

could be used to replace the file-generation.
Having forced any variables that start coverage to be "set to nothing" (just in case they're already set),
set the names of the fields you want to inspect.
Read the file/output, setting %%b to the string before the colon and %%c to the string between the colon and the . (I'm assuming that the lines to be detected are of the form string: integer.unwantedstring)
to filter only the required fields, attempt to match the string part to one of the required fields, then set coverage_string to the integer
Then use set coverage_ to list all of the variables and values in the form COVERAGE_string=value. Use delims of _ and = to pick the second and rest (=value) and if the value is less than the required threshhold, do something. I set the threshhold to 97 so that the message would appear with your sample data.
Then, just for demonstration, list the coverage values found.

is there any way to alter my trial?

Sorry - I have no idea what you mean.

can you please have a look at edited code
